# How do I solve this Mongodb "code": 11000?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been on this for long now. I can't seem to find solution anywhere. I am working a a blog application using Node, expressjs and mongodb. I created a comment system where users can comment on individual blog posts. The issue is that users can only make a single comment. If they try to make comment again, I get a mongodb erro. Here is the error:

```
"name": "MongoError",
"index": 0,
"code": 11000,
"keyPattern": {
    "title": 1
},
"keyValue": {
    "title": null
}
}
```

I sensed the error is coming from my Post schema model. Here is the code:

```
//creating the user models for the database

const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
   
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true, 
    },
    postPhoto:{
        type: String,
        required:false,
    },
   username:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'
    },
    categories:{
       type: Array,
    },
   comments: [{
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'Comment'
       }]
   
    }, {timestamps: true},

   );
 //exporting this schema
  module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema); //the module name is "Post"
```

This is my Comment Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose to be used
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true, 
    },
   author:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'
    },
   
  postId:{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Post',
         partialFilterExpression: { postId: { $type: 'string' } }
  }
  }, {timestamps: true}
  );
  //exporting this schema
 module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", CommentSchema); //the module name is "Post"
```

**This is my comment create new comment codes:**

```
/creating catergory logic

 router.post("/posts/:id/comment", async (req, res) =>{
 const newComment = new Comment(req.body);//we create a new comment for the database
    
 try{
    const savedComment = await newComment.save();//we need to try and catch the new comment and save it

    const currentPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id)//we need to find the post that has the comment via the id
        currentPost.comments.push(savedComment)//we need to push the comment into the post
       

       await currentPost.save()//we saved the new post with the comment
    res.status(200).json(currentPost)
 }catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err)
 }
 })
```

Comment: could you provide `req.body` for adding comments

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. The code to add comment is what I posted up there with a bold title: "This is my comment create new comment codes:"

Comment: note code you json request

Comment: I really wish i know what you're asking of me. I am actually still on a learning journey. Do help me explain better what you asked from me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After router.post ,console.log(req.body) and provide it

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have actually seen the solution. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

So, I eventually solved this. What happened was that I initially created a 'title' field in my Comment Model. I deleted it later.. But I didn't know that it has been indexed in my Mongodb alias. That needed to be deleted manually. Go to your MongoDB collections. Check the tab, you will see 'indexes', open it and check for the field that was returning the null error. In my case, it was title. I deleted it from the indexes menu and my problem was solved. You may try this if you are having similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to indexes in your collection.
You will find that some of the indexes are of the same name.

Another reason could be that you are giving multiple queries of duplicate data.