# Can't create a new Post (API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, mongoose

I can only create one user post under one username. So when I try to create a new post from another username or create a new post under the same name, this error shows.

Example: > elaine created a new first post. It worked. But when I try to create a new post under him, it won't work, and receive the error.

```
{
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "keyPattern": {
        "username": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
        "username": "elaine"
    }
}
```

> So I tried to create a new user and create a new post under the user but I received
> this error
> https://ibb.co/0yzSvb5

```
{
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "keyPattern": {
        "email": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
        "email": null
    }
}
```

**post.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router()

//I'm pulling the USER from models
const User = require('../Models/User')
const Post = require('../Models/Post')

//to unencrpt

//THIS IS CRUD
//CREATE POST -- PUT METHOD USE IN UPDATING  (/:id ) => user id
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const newPost = new Post(req.body)
  try {
    const savedPost = await newPost.save()
    res.status(200).json(savedPost)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }
})



module.exports = router
```

**PostSchema.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    photo: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    categories: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema)
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 5000
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth')
const userRoute = require('./routes/users')
const postRoute = require('./routes/posts')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

dotenv.config()
app.use(express.json())

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
  .then(console.log('Connected'))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))

//Calling auth route
app.use('/api/auth', authRoute)
app.use('/api/users', userRoute)
app.use('/api/posts', postRoute)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

userSchema.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    profilePic: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Comment: could you provide user schema ?

Comment: thank you pls provide `postRoute` function

Comment: @mohammadNaimi it's already there, the Update, Delete and Get is working properly, but the only problem is I can't create another one. 

the post.js

Comment: i think the title of new post is same and duplicate occured

Comment: @mohammadNaimi it wont work the api shows

{
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "keyPattern": {
        "username": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
        "username": "elaine"
    }
}

Comment: maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108904/5911891

Answer (score 0):

This error came from your schema.you are use `unique : true` constraints.so that mongoose can not get same values data. Everytime you need to add different values.And second option is remove `unique : true` constraints. Example :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    profilePic: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```